# Workflow showing error when i click to start "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow"

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When i click to start the workflow show alert "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" after that nothing happen

[image]

Comment: did u recycle workflow manger?  also check this post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ea8eda1c-4fb7-4e39-95e6-d37f6ef4ccf5/something-went-wrong-to-try-again-reload-the-page-and-then-start-the-workflow-error-on-starting-a?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Yes i did it but not work.

Comment: Its happen only my old workflow when i create new workflow it work.

Comment: any additional information in ULS log on the server? Does the workflow work on a list with a hyperlink field?

Comment: There is no any hyperlink field.

Comment: and what about entries in the Log in 15 Hive? Another advice would be to check the receivers / properties by 'SharePoint Manager' (https://spm.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hi John. Did you solve the issue. I am facing similar issue. My workflow is working if I create a new one but old ones re throwing error "Something went wrong"